# Using an anonymous function in Python

Tags: python, anonymous-function

I've got some code which downloads a list of data from numerous URLs, then calls another function, passing in each result. Something like...

```
def ShowUrls(self, url):
    Urls = self.Scraper.GetSubUrls(url)
    for Url in Urls:
        self.UI.addLink(
          Url[0],
          Url[1])
```

This works fine but there's a long delay while `self.Scraper.GetSubUrls` runs, then all the UI calls are made very rapidly. This causes the UI to show "0 Urls added" for a long time, then complete.

What I'd like is to be able to pass the `self.UI.addlink` method in to the `self.Scraper.GetSubUrls` method so that it can be called as soon as each URL is retrieved. This should make the UI show the correct count as soon as each url is retrieved.

Is this possible? If so, what's the correct syntax?

If I were in Javascript, I'd do something like....

```
getSubUrls(url, function(x, y) {UI.addLink(x, y)})
```

and then, inside getSubUrls do

```
SomeParamMethod(Pram1, Param2)
```

Is this possible? If so, what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda), but it's usually a better idea to make a separate function and pass it.

```
self.Scraper.GetSubUrls(url, lambda url: self.UI.addLink(url[0], url[1]))
```

or

```
def addLink(url):
    self.UI.addLink(url[0], url[1])

self.Scraper.GetSubUrls(url, addLink)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you clarify slightly - what's the preferred syntax and why?

Comment: @Basic: Sorry, updated with a link to the documentation and the better version. (Note that you nest the definition inside the other one.) It's preferred because it looks better and usually makes for cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks very much, that seems to be be exactly what I was after. I'll accept when I can

Comment: Just gonna throw in my two cents: `lamda` is generally best used in a place where a very simple functionality needs to happen just once. For instance, if you us it in something that loops like e.g. a list comprehension, Python will need to re-construct the function on every iteration, whereas if you pass a pre-defined function, it merely looks up the name.

Answer (score 6):

This suggestion is a bit more involved, but if you control `GetSubUrls`, a more Pythonic approach might be to make it a generator that yields each URL as it is retrieved.  You can then process each URL outside the function in a for loop.  For instance, I'm assuming `GetSubUrls` presumably looks something vaguely like this:

```
def GetSubUrls(self, url):
    urls = []
    document = openUrl(url)
    for stuff in document:
        urls.append(stuff)
    return urls
```

That is, it builds a list of URLs and returns the whole list.  You can make it a generator:

```
def GetSubUrls(self, url):
    document = openUrl(url)
    for stuff in document:
        yield stuff
```

Then you can just do

```
for url in self.Scraper.GetSubUrls(url):
    self.UI.addlink(url[0], url[1])
```

Which is the same as before, but if `GetSubUrls` is a generator, it doesn't wait to collect all the suburls and then return them.  It just yields one at a time, and your code can likewise process them one at a time.

One advantage of this over passing a callback is that you can store the generator and use it whenever you want, instead of having the calls made inside `GetSubUrls`.  That is, you can do `urls = GetSubUrls(url)`, save that for later, and still iterate over the URLs "on demand" at a later time, when they will be retrieved one by one.  Using a callback approach forces the `GetSubUrls` function to process all the URLs right away.  Another advantage is that you needn't create a bunch of small callbacks with little content; instead you can write these one-liners naturally as the body of the for loop.

Read up on Python generators for more info on this (for instance [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) ).

Comment: Yep, that's a good assumption re: `GetSubUrls()` and I like this approach - reminds me of Yielding in other languages. I've implemented minitech's answer so have awarded to him but +1 as I think I'm mgoing to come back and try to get your approach working as soon as I get the chance. Thanks